# Windows 7 license with different language

Tags: windows-7, license, language

I have a Hungarian Windows 7 license.

Can I install an English Windows 7 with it?

Is it legal?

Comment: Which version of Windows 7 is it, I know Ultimate allows for different languages anyway.

Comment: Professional...

Comment: Try and see of it activates?

Comment: That is what I wouldn't like to try. I'll get the key later but I'll need the PC until then. SO.. yeah. All I can do is report back then it seems. Thought someone knows the answer.

Comment: It turned out that I got an original boxed ENGLISH copy and MUI packs for it. So if anyone can answer this, go on ..but I wont be able. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried, it doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 2):

From Microsoft: [How do I get additional display languages?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-get-additional-display-languages)

You can add display languages by installing additional language files. When you install language files, you can view wizards, dialog boxes, menus, Help topics, and other items in Windows in a different language.

There are two types of language files:

1. **Windows 7 language packs:‌** Windows 7 language packs provide a translated version of most of the user interface. Language packs require a license and are ***available only in Windows 7 Ultimate and Windows 7 Enterprise***. Language packs are available through Windows Update as optional updates. They aren't installed automatically.
2. **Windows 7 Language Interface Pack (LIP):**‌ Windows 7  LIPs provide a translated version of the most widely used areas of the user interface. LIPs are freely available to download. Because not all of the user interface is translated, LIPs require at least one parent language. The parts of the user interface that aren't translated into the LIP language are displayed in the parent language. When you download the LIP, you get the parent language requirements for that language. The parent language pack needs to be installed before the LIP can be installed. For more information, including a list of languages available for downloading, go to the [Microsoft Local Language Program](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=66923) website.

Comment: That's what I don't want. I mean.. when you install a hungarian version, you get strange folder names, everything is FUBAR. If you install a language pack, its a bit better. But I want only english, and I've got a Professional license.